# Render or redirect when user role is specified

Tags: django, django-views, django-permissions

I'm building app using django (for note that i'm very very new to django). I want to add redirection from this existing view.

Object inside the view:

```
from core.views import generic

class ListViewPublic(generic.ListView):
    pass

class BookListView(ListViewPublic):
    model = Book

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_kwargs = {
            'status': Book.STATUS.public,
        }
        return Book.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = SearchForm(load_all=True)
        context.update({'form': form})
        return context
```

e.g.

- Given user is not logged in, it should be render the page
- Given user has **reader** as its role, it should be render the page
- Given user has **author** as its role, it should be redirect to **`/author`** url

How can I achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. For your custom needs like it should redirect to /author you have to create customize decorator. Something like this.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.template import RequestContext, Context
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, render

def custom_login_required(f):

    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
           this will check user is logged in , if not it will redirect to login page
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.user_profile.role=='author':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/author')
        else:
            return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = f.__name__
    return wrap
```

and write above get_context_data something like this.

```
@method_decorator(custom_login_required)
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = SearchForm(load_all=True)
        context.update({'form': form})
        return context
```

Comment: hi @Pawan Thanks for your visit and your answer. I added `custom_login_required` on the top of the file then put `@method_decorator` above `get_context_data` but i got error `wrap() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`. Any clue for it?